# Save previous function call values

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to get the locations of clicked buttons in tkinter. Everytime a button is clicked I want to save the location the button was placed in. However, once two buttons have been clicked/the function has been called twice, I want to store both the previous values and the new values together e.g. in a list, so that I can draw a line between the locations.
Here's what I have so far.

```
class ImageButton(CreateButton):
    def __init__(self, parent, image, command, location):
        Button.__init__(self, parent, image=image, command=command)
        self.image = image
        self.style = {
            "bg": "#7d7d7d",
            "bd": 0,
            "highlightbackground": "#000000",
            "highlightthickness": 0
        }
        self.place(x=location[0], y=location[1])
        self.config(self.style)


class MainGui(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Window.__init__(self, "Window", "800x500")
        self.called = 0

        self.airfields_btn = []
        self.airfields_btn.append(
            ImageButton(self, self.r_vfr, lambda: showinfo(icao_codes[0]),
                        [260, 375]))
        self.airfields_btn.append(
            ImageButton(self, self.r_vfr, lambda: showinfo(icao_codes[1]),
                        [205, 270]))

    def set_vector(self):
        self.count = self.count + 1
        if (self.count % 2) != 0:
            index = 0
            btn_id = 0
            for items in self.airfields_btn:
                items.config(
                    command=lambda index=index: self.get_location(index))
                index = index + 1
        else:
            self.canvas.delete(self.line)

    def get_location(self, index):
        placement = []
        self.called = self.called + 1
        if (self.called % 2) != 0:
            placement.append(self.airfields_btn[index].winfo_rootx())
            placement.append(self.airfields_btn[index].winfo_rooty())
        else:
            placement.append(self.airfields_btn[index].winfo_rootx())
            placement.append(self.airfields_btn[index].winfo_rooty())

    def vector(self, placement):
        x1, y1 = placement[0], placement[1]
        x2, y2 = placement[2], placement[3]

        self.canvas.delete(self.line)
        self.line = self.canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="White", width=3, dash=(10,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make the `placement` list an instance attribute of the `MainGui` class.

For example:

```
class MainGui(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Window.__init__(self, "Window", "800x500")
        self.called = 0
        self.placement = []      # added this
        self.airfields_btn = []
        self.airfields_btn.append(
            ImageButton(self, self.r_vfr, lambda: showinfo(icao_codes[0]),
                        [260, 375]))
        self.airfields_btn.append(
            ImageButton(self, self.r_vfr, lambda: showinfo(icao_codes[1]),
                        [205, 270]))

    def set_vector(self):
        self.count = self.count + 1
        if (self.count % 2) != 0:
            index = 0
            btn_id = 0
            for items in self.airfields_btn:
                items.config(
                    command=lambda index=index: self.get_location(index))
                index = index + 1
        else:
            self.canvas.delete(self.line)

    def get_location(self, index):    # <-- changed this
        self.called = self.called + 1
        btn = self.airfields_btn[index]
        self.placement.append( (btn.winfo_rootx(), btn.winfo_rooty()) )

    def vector(self, placement):       
        x1, y1 = self.placement[0]   # < changed this
        x2, y2 = self.placement[1]   # < changed this

        self.canvas.delete(self.line)
        self.line = self.canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="White", width=3, dash=(10,5))
```